# Postman posting null values to database

Tags: spring-boot

I'm post json body to my api and one column is being stored as null in my database

[image: Here is my posting of json body]

[image: One column is stored as null]

[image: Entity]

[image: controller]

[image: service layer]

I have tried multiple databases like h2 same problem with every database

Comment: #1 Post the code, not the images. #2 Print the values to the console before the insert and share us the result #3 Markdown for images is ![foo](url image). Check https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/d0753aa313676e260df416e3b50b7fbc#file-stackoverflow-tips-images-md #4 If you want a direct help,  use github to upload a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My guess is that "Role" is not being bound from JSON as it does not follow the JavaBeans naming convention. Please dont post images of code - you are likely to get downvoted: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

My Humble suggestion is to put the attribute 'Role' in small case 'role',

```
Private String role;
```

and I advise you to use DTO in the data transferring process, instead of the entity itself.